# Javascript timing problem

Tags: javascript, html, timing

I wont to run a block of code in a certain amount of time and then when done, carry on with another block of code.

Comment: so???? what do you want? Please prove more information. Some code .. etc

Comment: Perhaps his issue is with the fact that after setTimeout is set, javascript immediately continues executing the rest of his script? If this is the case you need to make setTimeout call a function, and inside this function that you call, call the function you want to run on completion.

Comment: Are you interested in using a framework?  MooTools has a slick chaining interface to make this a snap.

Answer (score 2):

Using the setTimeout() is probably what you want. For example...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function YourFunction()
    {
        alert('Hello Stackoverflow');
    }

    window.setTimeout(YourFunction, 1000);
</script>
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

This is how you would do it, using the [`setTimeout`](http://www.w3schools.com/htmldom/met%5Fwin%5Fsettimeout.asp) function, which takes code to call as the first argument and how much time it should wait before calling it (in milliseconds) as the second argument:

```
function callWhenDone() {
    // code to call when timeout finishes
}

setTimeout(function() {
    // initial code to run
    callWhenDone();
}, 5000); // 5000 = run in 5 seconds
```

Because of the nature of Javascript you have to encapsulate the code you want to run after the timeout is finished in its own function, otherwise it would be run before the timeout is finished. This is, in essense, a [callback](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_(computer_science)), and it is a big part of the event-based nature of Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use the [setTimeout()](http://www.w3schools.com/htmldom/met_win_settimeout.asp) function.

Answer (score 0):

**setTimeout** - executes code after a time interval

**clearTimeout** - cancels the setTimeout()

More details [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp).

Answer (score 0):

Use `setTimeout`.

```
setTimeout(function() {
    // code here
    // you can use it recursively
    //   setTimeout(...);
  },
  1000 // 1000 miliseconds (= 1 second)
);
```

and `setInterval` is like `setTimeout`, except it repeats a code repeatedly.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var timer = setInterval("firstFunction()","1000"); //every second call firstFunction()
var i = 0;

function firstFunction()
{

    //first code

    i++;
    if(i == 3)
    {
        clearInterval(timer);
        secondFunction();
    }
}

function secondFunction()
{
    //second code
    alert("done!");
}

</script>
```